# Converting the code from SimpleBaseGameActivity to BaseGameActivity AndEndgine GLES2

Tags: android, andengine

I'm fairly new to AndEngine Android programming and I don't know how to convert my SimpleBaseGameActivity code to BaseGameActivity. I want to convert it to match the tutorial i found on BaseGameActivity Splash + Menu tutorial so that I'll be able to merge it all.

Here's the code for the Tower of Hanoi Game:

```
public class MainActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {
private ITexture main_font_texture;
Text countText;
Font main_font; 
int movesCount;
Scene scene = new Scene();
private static int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
private static int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

private ITextureRegion mBackgroundTextureRegion, mTowerTextureRegion, mRing1, mRing2, mRing3;
private Stack<Ring> mStack1, mStack2, mStack3;
private Sprite mTower1, mTower2, mTower3;

@Override

public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
}

@Override

protected void onCreateResources() {


    try {

         main_font = FontFactory.create(this.getFontManager(), this.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA, Typeface.DEFAULT, 60, true, Color.BLACK_ABGR_PACKED_INT);
         main_font.load();


        ITexture backgroundTexture = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/background.png");
            }
        });

        ITexture towerTexture = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {

            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/tower.png");
            }
        });

        ITexture ring1 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {

            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/ring1.png");
            }
        });

        ITexture ring2 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {

            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/ring2.png");
            }
        });
        ITexture ring3 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {

            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/ring3.png");
            }
        });
        backgroundTexture.load();
        towerTexture.load();
        ring1.load();
        ring2.load();
        ring3.load();

        this.mBackgroundTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(backgroundTexture);
        this.mTowerTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(towerTexture);
        this.mRing1 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring1);
        this.mRing2 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring2);
        this.mRing3 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring3);

        this.mStack1 = new Stack<Ring>();
        this.mStack2 = new Stack<Ring>();
        this.mStack3 = new Stack<Ring>();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Debug.e(e);
    }
}

@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene() {



    Sprite backgroundSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, this.mBackgroundTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    mTower1 = new Sprite(0.241f * CAMERA_WIDTH, 0.133f * CAMERA_HEIGHT, this.mTowerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    mTower2 = new Sprite(0.5f * CAMERA_WIDTH, 0.133f * CAMERA_HEIGHT, this.mTowerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    mTower3 = new Sprite(0.756f * CAMERA_WIDTH, 0.133f * CAMERA_HEIGHT, this.mTowerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    Ring ring1 = new Ring(1, 139, 174, this.mRing1, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {

        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            if(this.getmStack().peek().getmWeight() != this.getmWeight())
                return false;
            this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                checkForCollisionsWithTowers(this);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    Ring ring2 = new Ring(2, 118, 212, this.mRing2, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {

        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            if(this.getmStack().peek().getmWeight() != this.getmWeight())
                return false;
            this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                checkForCollisionsWithTowers(this);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    Ring ring3 = new Ring(3, 97, 255, this.mRing3, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {

        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            if(this.getmStack().peek().getmWeight() != this.getmWeight())
                return false;
            this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                checkForCollisionsWithTowers(this);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    this.mStack1.add(ring3);
    this.mStack1.add(ring2);
    this.mStack1.add(ring1);

    ring1.setmStack(mStack1);
    ring2.setmStack(mStack1);
    ring3.setmStack(mStack1);
    ring1.setmTower(mTower1);
    ring2.setmTower(mTower1);
    ring3.setmTower(mTower1);

    scene.attachChild(backgroundSprite);
    scene.attachChild(mTower1);
    scene.attachChild(mTower2);
    scene.attachChild(mTower3);
    scene.attachChild(ring1);
    scene.attachChild(ring2);
    scene.attachChild(ring3);
    scene.registerTouchArea(ring1);
    scene.registerTouchArea(ring2);
    scene.registerTouchArea(ring3);

    scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);



   countText = new Text(0, 0, main_font, "Moves:" + movesCount ,10,  this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
     countText.setPosition(0,0);
     scene.attachChild(countText);


    return scene;
}


private void checkForCollisionsWithTowers(Ring ring) {
    Stack<Ring> stack = null;
    Sprite tower = null;

    if (ring.collidesWith(mTower1) && (mStack1.size() == 0 || ring.getmWeight() < mStack1.peek().getmWeight())) {
        stack = mStack1;
        tower = mTower1;
        movesCount++;
        countText.setText("Moves: "+ movesCount);

    } else if (ring.collidesWith(mTower2) && (mStack2.size() == 0 || ring.getmWeight() < mStack2.peek().getmWeight())) {
        stack = mStack2;
        tower = mTower2;
        movesCount++;
        countText.setText("Moves: "+ movesCount);


    } else if (ring.collidesWith(mTower3) && (mStack3.size() == 0 || ring.getmWeight() < mStack3.peek().getmWeight())) {
        stack = mStack3;
        tower = mTower3;
        movesCount++;
        countText.setText("Moves: "+ movesCount);

    } else {
        stack = ring.getmStack();
        tower = ring.getmTower();


    }
    ring.getmStack().remove(ring);
    if (stack != null && tower !=null && stack.size() == 0) {
        ring.setPosition(tower.getX() + tower.getWidth()/2 - ring.getWidth()/2, tower.getY() + tower.getHeight() - ring.getHeight());

    } else if (stack != null && tower !=null && stack.size() > 0) {
        ring.setPosition(tower.getX() + tower.getWidth()/2 - ring.getWidth()/2, stack.peek().getY() - ring.getHeight());

    }
    stack.add(ring);
    ring.setmStack(stack);
    ring.setmTower(tower);


    isGameOver();


}



private void isGameOver(){

    if(mStack3.size() == 3){

         Font main_font = FontFactory.create(this.getFontManager(), this.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA, Typeface.DEFAULT, 60, true, Color.BLACK_ABGR_PACKED_INT);
         main_font.load();

         Text levelCompleteText = new Text(0, 0, main_font, "Level Complete!" , this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
         levelCompleteText.setPosition(CAMERA_WIDTH/2 - levelCompleteText.getWidth()/2, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2 - levelCompleteText.getHeight()/2);
         scene.attachChild(levelCompleteText);
         scene.clearTouchAreas();


   }
}
    }
```

Here's for the Ring.java :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Ring extends Sprite {

private int mWeight;
private Stack<Ring> mStack; //this represents the stack that this ring belongs to
private Sprite mTower;

public Ring(int weight, float pX, float pY, ITextureRegion pTextureRegion, VertexBufferObjectManager pVertexBufferObjectManager) {
    super(pX, pY, pTextureRegion, pVertexBufferObjectManager);
    this.mWeight = weight;
}

public int getmWeight() {
    return mWeight;
}

public Stack<Ring> getmStack() {
    return mStack;
}

public void setmStack(Stack<Ring> mStack) {
    this.mStack = mStack;
}

public Sprite getmTower() {
    return mTower;
}

public void setmTower(Sprite mTower) {
    this.mTower = mTower;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package org.farook.towerofhanoi;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Stack;

import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.handler.timer.ITimerCallback;
import org.andengine.engine.handler.timer.TimerHandler;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.andengine.entity.text.Text;
import org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent;
import org.andengine.opengl.font.Font;
import org.andengine.opengl.font.FontFactory;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.ITexture;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.bitmap.BitmapTexture;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.bitmap.BitmapTextureFormat;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.ITextureRegion;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.region.TextureRegionFactory;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity;
import org.andengine.util.adt.io.in.IInputStreamOpener;
import org.andengine.util.color.Color;
import org.andengine.util.debug.Debug;

import android.graphics.Typeface;

public class TowerOfHanoiActivity extends BaseGameActivity {
    private static int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
    private static int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
    private ITextureRegion mBackgroundTextureRegion, mTowerTextureRegion, mRing1, mRing2, mRing3;
    private Sprite mTower1, mTower2, mTower3;
    private Stack<Ring> mStack1, mStack2, mStack3;
      Text countText;
      Font main_font;
      int movesCount;
    Scene scene;
    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateResources(OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback) throws Exception {

        try {


            main_font = FontFactory.create(this.getFontManager(), this.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, BitmapTextureFormat.RGBA_8888, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA, Typeface.DEFAULT, 60, true, Color.BLACK_ABGR_PACKED_INT);
            main_font.load();


             BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

            // 1 - Set up bitmap textures
            ITexture backgroundTexture = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("gfx/background.png");
                }
            });
            ITexture towerTexture = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("gfx/tower.png");
                }
            });
            ITexture ring1 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("gfx/ring1.png");
                }
            });
            ITexture ring2 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("gfx/ring2.png");
                }
            });
            ITexture ring3 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                    return getAssets().open("gfx/ring3.png");
                }
            });
            // 2 - Load bitmap textures into VRAM
            backgroundTexture.load();
            towerTexture.load();
            ring1.load();
            ring2.load();
            ring3.load();
            // 3 - Set up texture regions
            this.mBackgroundTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(backgroundTexture);
            this.mTowerTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(towerTexture);
            this.mRing1 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring1);
            this.mRing2 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring2);
            this.mRing3 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring3);
            // 4 - Create the stacks
            this.mStack1 = new Stack<Ring>();
            this.mStack2 = new Stack<Ring>();
            this.mStack3 = new Stack<Ring>();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Debug.e(e);
        }

        pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback) throws Exception {

        // 1 - Create new scene
                scene = new Scene();
                Sprite backgroundSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, this.mBackgroundTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                scene.attachChild(backgroundSprite);

                // 2 - Add the towers
                mTower1 = new Sprite(192, 63, this.mTowerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                mTower2 = new Sprite(400, 63, this.mTowerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                mTower3 = new Sprite(604, 63, this.mTowerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());

                mTower1.setTag(1);
                mTower2.setTag(2);
                mTower3.setTag(3);

                scene.attachChild(mTower1);
                scene.attachChild(mTower2);
                scene.attachChild(mTower3);

                // 3 - Create the rings
                Ring ring1 = new Ring(1, 139, 174, this.mRing1, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                        if (((Ring) this.getmStack().peek()).getmWeight() != this.getmWeight())
                            return false;
                        this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
                        if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                            checkForCollisionsWithTowers(this);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                };
                Ring ring2 = new Ring(2, 118, 212, this.mRing2, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                        if (((Ring) this.getmStack().peek()).getmWeight() != this.getmWeight())
                            return false;
                        this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
                        if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                            checkForCollisionsWithTowers(this);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                };
                Ring ring3 = new Ring(3, 97, 255, this.mRing3, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                        if (((Ring) this.getmStack().peek()).getmWeight() != this.getmWeight())
                            return false;
                        this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
                        if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                            checkForCollisionsWithTowers(this);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                };
                scene.attachChild(ring1);
                scene.attachChild(ring2);
                scene.attachChild(ring3);
                // 4 - Add all rings to stack one
                this.mStack1.add(ring3);
                this.mStack1.add(ring2);
                this.mStack1.add(ring1);
                // 5 - Initialize starting position for each ring
                ring1.setmStack(mStack1);
                ring2.setmStack(mStack1);
                ring3.setmStack(mStack1);
                ring1.setmTower(mTower1);
                ring2.setmTower(mTower1);
                ring3.setmTower(mTower1);
                // 6 - Add touch handlers
                scene.registerTouchArea(ring1);
                scene.registerTouchArea(ring2);
                scene.registerTouchArea(ring3);
                scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);

                countText = new Text(0, 0, main_font, "Moves:" + movesCount ,10,  this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                countText.setPosition(CAMERA_WIDTH - countText.getWidth(), 10);
                scene.attachChild(countText);

                pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(scene);

    }



       @Override
       public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene, OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws IOException {

           //LOAD YOUR RESOURCES AND SCENES


           pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();

       }


        private void checkForCollisionsWithTowers(Ring ring) {
            Stack<Ring> stack = null;
            Sprite tower = null;

            boolean isRingUpdated = false;
            if (ring.collidesWith(mTower1) && (mStack1.size() == 0 || ring.getmWeight() < ((Ring) mStack1.peek()).getmWeight())) {
                stack = mStack1;
                tower = mTower1;

               isRingUpdated = checkIsRingUpdated(ring, mTower1);

            } else if (ring.collidesWith(mTower2) && (mStack2.size() == 0 || ring.getmWeight() < ((Ring) mStack2.peek()).getmWeight())) {
                stack = mStack2;
                tower = mTower2;

                isRingUpdated =  checkIsRingUpdated(ring, mTower2);
            } else if (ring.collidesWith(mTower3) && (mStack3.size() == 0 || ring.getmWeight() < ((Ring) mStack3.peek()).getmWeight())) {
                stack = mStack3;
                tower = mTower3;

                isRingUpdated =   checkIsRingUpdated(ring, mTower3);
            } else {
                stack = ring.getmStack();
                tower = ring.getmTower();
            }
            ring.getmStack().remove(ring);
            if (stack != null && tower !=null && stack.size() == 0) {
                ring.setPosition(tower.getX() + tower.getWidth()/2 - ring.getWidth()/2, tower.getY() + tower.getHeight() - ring.getHeight());
            } else if (stack != null && tower !=null && stack.size() > 0) {
                ring.setPosition(tower.getX() + tower.getWidth()/2 - ring.getWidth()/2, ((Ring) stack.peek()).getY() - ring.getHeight());
            }
            stack.add(ring);
            ring.setmStack(stack);
            ring.setmTower(tower);


            if(isRingUpdated){
                movesCount++;
                if(countText != null){
                    countText.setText("Moves:"+ movesCount);
                }

            }

            isGameOver();
        }

        private boolean checkIsRingUpdated(Ring ring, Sprite mTower) { 
            if(ring.getmTower().getTag() != mTower.getTag()){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void isGameOver() {
            if(mStack3.size() == 3){

                 Text gameOverText = new Text(0, 0, main_font, "GameOver", this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
                 gameOverText.setPosition(CAMERA_WIDTH/2 - gameOverText.getWidth()/2, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2 - gameOverText.getHeight()/2);
                 scene.attachChild(gameOverText);

                 scene.clearTouchAreas();
           }

            }

}
```

Comment: check the post.It may help you.

Comment: The code works Rama. Thanks! I like the way you did the boolean isringUpdated instead of the count++; on every else if statement. haha Thanks man!