# NullPointerException with AndEngine

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, andengine

I added and engine to Android studio according to [this tutorial](http://javaprogrammernotes.blogspot.com/2014/05/settings-up-andengine-in-android-studio.html).

However, when simply creating a GameActivity extending from SimpleBaseGameActivity, I get this error:

Here's my GameActivity code:

```
public class GameActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {
    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreateResources() throws IOException {

    }

    @Override
    protected Scene onCreateScene() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My manifest code:

```
 <activity
     android:name="com.waylonhuang.game.MainActivity"
     android:label="@string/app_name" >
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".GameActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

So here's the error: What am I missing?

```
547-547/com.waylonhuang.game E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.waylonhuang.game, PID: 547
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.waylonhuang.game/com.waylonhuang.game.GameActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.andengine.engine.Engine.<init>(Engine.java:145)
        at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onCreateEngine(BaseGameActivity.java:92)
        at org.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onCreate(BaseGameActivity.java:82)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)


 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You are returning a `null` in `onCreateEngineOptions()` and also in the method `onCreateScene()`. I hope if this link is helpful [Converting the code from SimpleBaseGameActivity to BaseGameActivity AndEndgine GLES2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21510774/converting-the-code-from-simplebasegameactivity-to-basegameactivity-andendgine-g)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use andEngine, but based off of what I see, it is probably because you are returning null for both the scene and engineoptions in the onCreateScene() and onCreateEngineOptions().

Comment: After doing some searching, I have determined that this is indeed your problem. Look at this tutorial on how to set up a basic hello world project with andEngine http://www.matim-dev.com/hello-world---basic-example.html